# How can I get the byte representation of a format!() String in a single expression?

Tags: rust

I am trying to format a string and then, *in one expression*, get a slice of `u8`s containing the byte representation of the string.

Running

```rs
format!("bedrijfpda{:0>3}", num).as_bytes()
```

gives me a `temporary value dropped while borrowed` error, but running

```rs
let val = format!("bedrijfpda{:0>3}", num);
let bytes = val.as_bytes();
```

gives me the result I want.

How can I do this **in one expression**?

Comment: You don't. Why does this need to be one expression?

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here, a `&[u8]` is a *reference* type, it only refers to data that is owned elsewhere. You can certainly get a `Vec<u8>` if you just want to own the bytes.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. If this **must** be a single expression (maybe your hard drive is full and cannot store the newlines?), convert it to a `Vec<u8>`:

```rust
format!("").into_bytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is stupid, but if you really want you can do that:

```rust
let v: &[u8] = &format!("bedrijfpda{:0>3}", num).into_bytes()[..];
```

The trick is that while methods calls are not subject to [temporary lifetime extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/destructors.html#temporary-lifetime-extension), indexing and borrowing are, so they extend the lifetime of the `Vec`.